# Using rvest to extract multiple tables within a page

Tags: r, rvest

How do I convert all the lists to a dataframe, append all the dataframes and export to csv?

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/21665/000144530512000409/exhibit21.htm")

tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
tbls_ls <- html_table(tbls,fill = TRUE)

colnames(tbls_ls[[1]]) <- c("Name", "Country")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all the tables from the link and bind them together using `bind_rows`

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/21665/000144530512000409/exhibit21.htm"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  bind_rows()
```

However, this would require a little cleaning and renaming afterwards since it doesn't identify column names separately.